# Connection refused Error cakephp

Tags: cakephp, smtp, cakephp-2.0, sendmail, shared-hosting

I can't send an email through a website that is that is hosted, on localhost it works normally, but since it was hosted it doesn't. I made the hosting by the godaddy.

email.php:

```
class EmailConfig {
public $smtp = array(
'transport' => 'Smtp',
'from' => array('rukacoradelo@gmail.com' => 'Matheus'),
'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
'port' => 587,
'timeout' => 30,
'username' => 'rukacoradelo@gmail.com',
'password' => '*********',
'client' => null,
'log' => false,
'charset' => 'utf-8',
'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
'tls' => 1,
);
}
```

Erro:

> Connection refused Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred. Stack Trace
>   CORE/Cake/Network/Email/SmtpTransport.php line 154 →
>   CakeSocket->connect() CORE/Cake/Network/Email/SmtpTransport.php line
>   95 → SmtpTransport->_connect() CORE/Cake/Network/Email/CakeEmail.php
>   line 1161 → SmtpTransport->send(CakeEmail)
>   APP/Controller/PagesController.php line 58 → CakeEmail->send()
>   [internal function] → PagesController->home()
>   CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 490 →
>   ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(PagesController, array)
>   CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 193 →
>   Controller->invokeAction(CakeRequest) CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php
>   line 167 → Dispatcher->_invoke(PagesController, CakeRequest)
>   APP/webroot/index.php line 108 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest,
>   CakeResponse)

Comment: Do you have to use gmail?  I'm pretty sure godaddy has SMTP support when your hosting your website with them.  They might be blocking outbound SMTP connections.

Comment: Outbound SMTP? I just want to send an email... I'm trying for over a month, but nothing... Please help me!!